# How is the t-statistic computed in this context?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

According to pg. 55 of *Statistics in Plain English*, the t-statistic for the sample mean is

$$
t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{s}
$$

where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, $\mu$ is the population mean, and $s$ is the **sample estimate of the standard error**.

**Question:** How is the sample estimate of the standard error computed in this context? In particular, does it make use of the population mean or the sample mean? That is, is it computed like this

$$
s = \sqrt{E[(S-\mu)^2]}
$$

or

$$
s = \sqrt{E[(S-\bar{x})^2]}?
$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean and $S$ is the sample from $X$ (the underlying random variable we are inspecting) viewed as a random variable.

Comment: What is $S$ ? Is it the sum of the outcomes ? Please specify the meaning of $S$.

Comment: $S$ is meant to be the observed sample taken as a random variable.

Comment: From where did you get this formula ?

Comment: I must be confused. I just wrote it down from my conceptual understanding. $S$ is calculated by observing $n$ data points from the unknown population $X$.

Comment: To calculate an estimator for the  standard deviation of the population  you cannot take $\mu$. You want to estimate the standard deviation based on the sample. You cannot mix it. The expected value under the root doesn´t make sense. It does make sense to calculate $E(s^2)$

Answer (score 0):

When you go for t statistic, it is assume that you do not know the population standard deviation.

To answer your question, the sample standard deviation is calculated based on the below formula

$$s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}(x_i -\bar x)^2}{n-1}}$$

Comment: Ok. But isn't it weird here to use $\bar{x}$ when you already know $\mu$ (whence you could use $\mu$ in the numerator and $n$ in the denominator)?

Comment: Also, just to clarify: this calculation $s$ is used to estimate the sample standard error via the computation $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, right?

Comment: The correct formula is $t = \frac{\bar x - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}},$ where $s$ is the sample SD as in this Answer according to fairly well established notation. So the formula in your 'plain English' book is using $s$ where standard notation uses $s/\sqrt{n}$ for the (estimated) standard error of $\bar x.$ The standard error is the SD of $\bar x,$ which is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ usually $estimated$ as $s/\sqrt{n}.$ This is a different thing than the sample SD $s$.